# How does one configure Apache Drill to use the Google GCS connector?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, apache-drill, bigdata

So I've read the documentation for enabling Plugins, but there doesn't seem to be a way to add new plugins other than for the ones already packaged.

I've tried grabbing the google cloud storage connector jar and sticking it in the 3rd party folder and starting Drill, but it doesn't seem to pick it up. I get an error that it doesn't recognise the protocol (gs://, as opposed to s3:// which works obviously).

Has any managed to do this? There seems to be zero information on getting this working, although Drill does claim to be able to work with google cloud services.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Drill using Google Cloud Storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883965/apache-drill-using-google-cloud-storage)